Remote Development for NetBeans 23
I have been using NetBeans 8 on my old computer for years. If I wanted to set up a remote host, all I had to do was right click on the project folder and select "Set Build Host" and then "Manage Hosts" to add a new one.
I am attempting to do the same thing on a new computer running NetBeans 23. When I right click, I do not receive the same options as on NetBeans 8. I have tried to google the answer but all I get is how to set it up on NetBeans 8...

This setting is in the Project Properties, just click on the Build in left pane:

Is it what you're asking?

Are you using NetBeans 23? When I click Project Properties and then Build, my window looks nothing like that. When I get back to my other computer, I'll take a screenshot and post it here so you can see what I am talking about. I was using NetBeans 23 on a computer running Ubuntu 20.04. It seemed a bit glitchy too. Like some of the buttons wouldn't fully render in the windows.

@Frank - yes, it's the netbeans 23, with c/c++ plugin from 8.2. Project type is "C/C++ project with existing sources". OS is xubuntu 22.04
